# Error: cb() never called when installing ionic cloud

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I don't understand why whenever I tried to install ionic cloud in my ionic v.1 project, I always get
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

I typed this on my cli
npm install @ionic/cloud --save

Is it because it's not backwards compatible since ionic has upgraded to v. 2 now?